# How to remove \n from a column using awk or sed

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have data:

```
1528198031|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202225|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse
1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202574|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203825|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203890|Andr|rail|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

I want to remove \n in column 4 using sed or awk if it possible. Result would look like this:

```
1528198031|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202225|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse 1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202574|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203825|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203890|Andr|rail|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Patterns before \n always different, it can be 1-9 or text, or symbols like `:`,`;`, `(`, `)`.

Text was changed, but formatting is like in original data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed` - join to the previous line if this line contains only non-pipe characters:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N; s/\n\([^|]*\)$/ \1/; ta' -e 'P;D' file
1528198031|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202225|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse 1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202574|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203825|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203890|Andr|rail|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```

Comment: Yeah, that's it. But I don't know why, it doesn't work with file, unless I open it and save manually. Then it works perfect.

Comment: @StrawberryHat your version of sed may have a `-i` or `--in-place` option that allows you to modify the contents of the file directly

Comment: tried with `-i`, still don't work without manually saving file. Tried to split file by 250 lines, change chmod - also doesn't work. 
upd: Sed version 4.5 March 2018  (that's how `man sed` print it)

Comment: @StrawberryHat perhaps the original file contains non-printing characters that are getting stripped out when you re-save the file? The usual culprits are carriage returns (from DOS-style CRLF line endings)

Comment: Yeah, you right! Added `-e 's/\r//g'` before your first `-e` and it's working now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk -F'|' '{ printf "%s%s", (NR == 1? "" : (NF > 1? ORS : OFS)), $0 }
           END{ print "" }' file
```

The output:

```
1528198031|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202225|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, conse 1) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 2) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit 3) Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elitLorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528202574|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203825|Andr|thund|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
1528203890|Andr|rail|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit
```