# How to remove newline in a column and merge it by using sed

Tags: bash, sed

How to remove newline in a column and merge it by using sed.

**`xlsx2csv rawdata.xlsx -n 'CONSOLIDATION MAIN' -d '|' | sed '1d-6d' |grep -v ^REGION >  RAWDATA.txt`**

[image]

Comment: You might want to include example data, your current output as well as the desired output if you expect anybody to help you

Comment: @mashuptwice how to add details/data for the current output as well as the desired output. Sorry, I'm new here. Thanks

Comment: By editing your question.

Comment: there is an 'Edit' link under your question, by clicking on that you will be able to edit and add details into your question. or click '[Edit]' here.

Comment: I just screenshot the Current Output vs the Expected Output. Thanks

Comment: What do you expect `sed '1d-6d'` to do?

Comment: Please don't add screenshots textual content, rather copy-paste the content and format as code.

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Comment: Do you maybe want `tr '\n' ' '` ?

Comment: Duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/449637/493832

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove \n from a column using awk or sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449637/how-to-remove-n-from-a-column-using-awk-or-sed)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(your command) | tr '\n' ' ' | sed -e 's/|`/|\n/g'
```

First replaces all newlines with a space and then

replaces |` (the end of your record) with a new line.